# Characterization of $\sigma(Y)$ measurable random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I cannot solve the following question. Please provide me some helps for dealing with this problem.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $Y$ be a mesurable random variable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$. Then define $$\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y) = Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}) = \{Y^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$$ where $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. If $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $X$ must be a function of $Y$, i.e., there exists a measurable function $f$ such that $$X = f(Y).$$

Comment: when you write $Y^{-1}(A)$ you mean $Y$ is the probability measure associated with some random variable $Z$ ?

Comment: Try using a monotone class theorem.

Comment: @user1952009 I do not quite understand what do you mean. My $\mathcal{G}$ is a collection of the inverse image of set in Borel sigma algebra. Actually, $\mathcal{G}$ is the sigma algebra generated by random variable $Y.$ ($\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$)

Answer (score 2):

First assume that $X$ is the characteristic function of an element of $\mathcal G$: which function $f$ would you choose?

Then assume that $X$ is a linear combination (with non-negative coefficients) of characteristic function of measurable sets (simple function). Since it is assumed to be $\mathcal G$-measurable, these sets are in $\mathcal G$. Which function $f$ would you choose?

Now, if $X$ is non-negative and $\mathcal G$-measurable, we can find a sequence of non-negative simple functions $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that $X_n(\omega)\uparrow X(\omega)$ for each $\omega\in \Omega$. We can write $X_n=f_n(Y)$. It remains to show that the sequence $\left(f_n(x)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is convergent for $x\in Y(\Omega)$.

Comment: Let $g = 1_{Y^{-1}(C)}$ for some $C$. Then I think that $$g = f(Y)$$ where $f = 1_C$. If this is correct, all the next steps follow standard measure theory technique. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I think you $g$ should be $X$. Indeed ,we choose such an $f$.

Comment: Yes, $g = X$. Thank you for your suggestion. For $X$ $\mathcal{G}-$measurable, I just deal with $X^+, X^-$ and use result from non-negative case. This should complete the proof. Is there any point I should pay be more careful (except just follow standard real anlysis) ?