# Inclusion of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $X_1, X_2, X_3$ three random variables taking values on $\mathbb{R}$, I want to see whether $\mathcal{F}_{X_1X_2}\subset \mathcal{F}_{X_1X_2X_3}$ or $\mathcal{F}_{X_1X_2}\supset \mathcal{F}_{X_1X_2X_3}$. My intuition tells me that $\mathcal{F}_{X_1X_2X_3}$ is greater because it contains more information, but I don't know how to justify it... Help, please? Thanks

Comment: And what is $\mathcal{F}_{X_1 X_2}$?

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1X_2$. Respectively, $\mathcal{F}_{X_1X_2X_3}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1X_2X_3$

Comment: You mean $X_1$ *and* $X_2$, right?

Comment: @Idéophage OP means the sigma-algebras generated by the moltiplication of the random variables

Comment: $X_1X_2$ is the product of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (same with $X_1X_2X_3$).

Comment: Ok, thanks! But then why would $X_1X_2X_3$ contain more information than $X_1X_2$? Does $8$ contain more information than $2$?

Comment: Actually that's a thing I'm telling myself, because I just think I'm confusing the product of r.v. with the cartesian product, I mean, if I take $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ rather than it's product; in that case there is more information when you consider the third component, but that information disappears as long as you make the product of the three r.v. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ there is no relation between the sigma algebras for $F_{X}, F_{Y}$ and $F_{XY}$. Applying this to $X=X_1X_2$ and $Y=X_3$, we conclude that it is possible to have $F_{X_1X_2}\not\subseteq F_{X_1X_2X_3}$ and $F_{X_1X_2}\not\supseteq F_{X_1X_2X_3}$.

It helps to look at an example. Let $\Omega=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ with the powerset $\sigma$-algebra and uniform measure, and let $X(\omega_1,\omega_2)=\omega_1$ and $Y(\omega_1,\omega_2)=\omega_2$. You can check that none of $F_X,F_Y$ and $F_{XY}$ include each other. Since $\sigma$-algebras on a finite set, $\Omega$,  are equivalent to partitions of $\Omega$, I find this is best illustrated as shown
$$
\mathcal F_X:\begin{array}{c|c}1 & 1 \\\hline \color{red}2 & \color{red}2\end{array}
\qquad
\mathcal F_Y:\begin{array}{c|c}1 & \color{red}2 \\\hline 1 & \color{red}2\end{array}
\qquad 
\mathcal F_{XY}:\begin{array}{c|c}1 & \color{red}2 \\\hline \color{red}2 & \color{orange}4\end{array}
$$

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question. Since there has been a bit of confusion with notation, I have been thinking on another problem: What about if we consider $\mathcal F_{X_1X_2, X_1X_3, X_2X_3}$ and $\mathcal F_{X_1, X_2, X_3}$?

Comment: @R_ Intuitively, if $\mathcal F$ is generated by a bunch of random variables, and $\mathcal G$ is generated by a different set of random variables, then $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal G$ if and only if each random variable for $\mathcal F$ can be written as a function of the variables defining $\mathcal G$. Therefore, we at least have $\mathcal F_{X_1X_2, X_1X_3, X_2X_3}\subseteq F_{X_1,X_2,X_3}$. As long as the random variables are nonzero, you also have the reverse inclusion. For example, $X_1$ can be written as a function of the products, via $X_1={X_1X_2\cdot X_1X_3\over X_2X_3}$.

Comment: Nice, clear. I understand easily the "if" part, but how can it be proved that if $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{G}$ then there exists such a function? Thanks!

Comment: @R__ For a proof where $\mathcal F=\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma(Y)$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729860/characterization-of-sigmay-measurable-random-variable. For more than one variables, you would need to do the same thing, but with $X$ and $Y$ being random vectors instead. I actually do not know the details of the proof, but this comment chain is getting to long, so maybe consider asking it as a separate question.

Comment: It's enough with that, I will work it out now. Thank you very very much!